# In Erlang, how to write a BFS Tree Search to find a specific node

Tags: erlang

I want to write a function to find a specific node in a BFS Tree Search.

How to do it in Erlang?

Comment: Since you are new to SO a few hints: avoid "hello" and similar clutter in questions and answers.  And it helps if you show more effort in your question e.g. what you tried and where you got stuck.  You got lucky this time but often you just don't get an answer if you appear too lazy when asking the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a simple structure:

```
node() :: {Key :: term(), Left :: node(), Right :: node()} | undefined.
```

This function would perform a breadth-first search over the tree and return the depth of the first element found (returns `false` if no node is found):

```
find(_Key, undefined) -> false;
find(Key,  Tree)      -> find(Key, [Tree], [], 0).

find(_Key, [], [], _Depth) -> % No more children
    false;
find(Key, [], Children, Depth) -> % Next level, increase depth
    find(Key, Children, [], Depth + 1);
find(Key, [{Key, _, _}|_Rest], _Children, Depth) -> % Found it!
    Depth;
find(Key, [{_, Left, Right}|Rest], Children, Depth) -> % Add children to search
    find(Key, Rest, add(Right, add(Left, Children)), Depth).

add(undefined, List) -> List;
add(E,         List) -> [E|List].
```

(An empty tree is just `undefined`).